# How to apply aspx master web page header and footer into asp.net mvc view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web site built by asp.net but now I want one webpage to be redirected to a newly created asp.net mvc view. Off course I would not convert the entire site from asp.net to asp.net mvc but I want only one mvc view embedded into the web site, keeping the original master page setting like heading, footer, etc. How can I achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: These are two very different architectures, so I'll be surprised if it's possible. In any case, please provide any code example of what you have tried so far. On StackOverflow, we help solve problems, we don't write your code.

Comment: Master =  webforms. But MVC has a `_Layout.chtml` which has a similar function.

Comment: Why don't you rebuild the equivalent of your master page as an MVC layout? Just convert any controls you have to Razor, plain HTML should be straightforward to move across.